# Jquery .load when posting HTML form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a JQUERY function i use to load pages into an existing div:

```
function OpenPage(pagename) {
    var page = pagename
    $('.tabcontent').load('/wp_pages/my_integra/pages/' + page);
}

<div class="tabcontent"></div>
```

My links look like: `<li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('home.php');">Home</a></li>`

this works great, but i am now looking to post a HTML form and displaying the action page inside this DIV rather than going to a new page

**UPDATE**

I have this function:

```
function SubmitForm(form, postaction) {
    $(form).submit(function(event){
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(postaction, data)
        .success(function(result){
            //console.log(result);
            $('.tabcontent').html(result);
        })
        .error(function(){
            $('.tabcontent').html('Error Loading Page');
            console.log('Error loading page');
        })
        return false;
    });
}
```

which works fine, how can i use something in PHP like

```
if(isset($_POST["buttonName"])) {
    ...run query
}
```

i have tried it, using the button name but its not working

Comment: So you're trying to submit a form and have the thank you page dynamically show instead of refreshing the page? Just confirming that's what you want.

Comment: my code above works fine for switching between pages etc using the div and .load in jquery  but im not sure how to do the same thing submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. replace the `url:` and `load page` of course.

```
var myform = $('#myform');
myform.submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/url/of/post/function",
  data: myform.serialize();
})
  .done(function( response ) {
    $('.tabcontent').load('/page/to/load/in/tab');
  });

});
```

Comment: got it - ; rather than , after   data: myform.serialize();

Comment: I will check and update my answer in a bit. Currently out of the house.